# What does underscoring methods connote?

Tags: python, double-underscore

I am relatively new to the Python language and encountered this in doing the following:

```
help(list)
```

Here is what I encountered:

```
__add__(...)
|      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
|  
|  __contains__(...)
|      x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
|  
|  __delitem__(...)
|      x.__delitem__(y) <==> del x[y]
```

Regarding these, what are the underscores for? Because they aren't used (to my knowledge) when you use a method normally, I'm struggling to understand why they'd take the time to write them out with underscores in the documentation.

Comment: It seems this is a frequently asked question amongst python newcomers.  Excellent resource: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Answer (score 10):

See [the Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a comprehensive explanation.

In practice:

```
the following special forms using leading or trailing
underscores are recognized (these can generally be combined with any case
convention):

- _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator.  E.g. "from M
  import *" does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

- single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with
  Python keyword, e.g.

  Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')

- __double_leading_underscore: when naming a class attribute, invokes name
  mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes _FooBar__boo; see below).

- __double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__: "magic" objects or
  attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces.  E.g. __init__,
  __import__ or __file__.  Never invent such names; only use them
  as documented.
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping a method name in underscores is just a way to separate namespaces. If a method begins and ends with underscores, it's simply a convention to indicate that the method isn't meant to be used by external code.

The blurb from `help(list)` you posted simply means that when you use Python's syntax to say `e in lst`, you're actually invoking `lst.__contains__(e)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, [explaining the use of double underscores](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html):

> ... rather than devising a new syntax
>   for special kinds of class methods
>   (such as initializers and
>   destructors), I decided that these
>   features could be handled by simply
>   requiring the user to implement
>   methods with special names such as
>   *init*, *del*, and so forth. This naming convention was taken from C
>   where identifiers starting with
>   underscores are reserved by the
>   compiler and often have special
>   meaning (e.g., macros such as *FILE*
>   in the C preprocessor).

...

> I also used this technique to allow user classes to redefine the
>   behavior of Python's operators. As
>   previously noted, Python is
>   implemented in C and uses tables of
>   function pointers to implement various
>   capabilities of built-in objects
>   (e.g., “get attribute”, “add” and
>   “call”). To allow these capabilities
>   to be defined in user-defined classes,
>   I mapped the various function pointers
>   to special method names such as
>   *getattr*, *add*, and *call*. There is a direct correspondence between these
>   names and the tables of function
>   pointers one has to define when
>   implementing new Python objects in C.

Also see the Python documentation on [special method names](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) which reads in part:

> A class can implement certain
>   operations that are invoked by special
>   syntax (such as arithmetic operations
>   or subscripting and slicing) by
>   defining methods with special names.
>   This is Python’s approach to operator
>   overloading, allowing classes to
>   define their own behavior with respect
>   to language operators.

Answer (score 0):

[They are special methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) (not the "dunder" (double underscore) makes them special, but most often they have a special meaning). They are often called when using operators. You can overwrite the behaviour in your classes.

E.g if you have a class `C`, by defining

```
class C:
    def __add__(self, other):
        #....
        return something
```

you can define what should happen if you add two instances from the class:

```
val = instance1 + instance2
```

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, these underscores are nothing special; they're just part of the method name.

However, they are used to indicate "magical" methods, such as constructors and overloaded operators. You should not use them in your own method names. From [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> - `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or
>       attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces.  E.g. `__init__`,
>       `__import__` or `__file__`.  Never invent such names; only use them
>       as documented.

You will rarely have to call any of these directly. For example:

- `MyClass(...)` will call `MyClass.__init__(...)`,
- `a + b` will call `a.__plus__(b)`,
- `str(a)` will call `a.__str__()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, double underscores are used as a convention to denote special methods - methods that are implemented to support syntactic sugar purposes and other special interfaces.

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames