# Methods that start and end with ___

Tags: python

I have noticed that in Python some of the fundamental types have two types of methods: those that are surrounded by `__` and those that don't.

For example, if I have a variable of type `float` called `my_number`, I can see in IPython that it has the following methods:

```
my_number.__abs__           my_number.__pos__
my_number.__add__           my_number.__pow__
my_number.__class__         my_number.__radd__
my_number.__coerce__        my_number.__rdiv__
my_number.__delattr__       my_number.__rdivmod__
my_number.__div__           my_number.__reduce__
my_number.__divmod__        my_number.__reduce_ex__
my_number.__doc__           my_number.__repr__
my_number.__eq__            my_number.__rfloordiv__
my_number.__float__         my_number.__rmod__
my_number.__floordiv__      my_number.__rmul__
my_number.__format__        my_number.__rpow__
my_number.__ge__            my_number.__rsub__
my_number.__getattribute__  my_number.__rtruediv__
my_number.__getformat__     my_number.__setattr__
my_number.__getnewargs__    my_number.__setformat__
my_number.__gt__            my_number.__sizeof__
my_number.__hash__          my_number.__str__
my_number.__init__          my_number.__sub__
my_number.__int__           my_number.__subclasshook__
my_number.__le__            my_number.__truediv__
my_number.__long__          my_number.__trunc__
my_number.__lt__            my_number.as_integer_ratio
my_number.__mod__           my_number.conjugate
my_number.__mul__           my_number.fromhex
my_number.__ne__            my_number.hex
my_number.__neg__           my_number.imag
my_number.__new__           my_number.is_integer
my_number.__nonzero__       my_number.real
```

1. What is the difference between those that are surrounded by `___`  and those that aren't?
2. Is this some sort of  **standard** used in other programming languages? Does it usually mean the same thing in similar languages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does underscoring methods connote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017282/what-does-underscoring-methods-connote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The variables you speak of __*__ are system variables or methods.

To quote the Python reference guide:

> System-defined names. These names are defined by the interpreter and its implementation (including the standard library); applications should not expect to define additional names using this convention. The set of names of this class defined by Python may be extended in future versions.

Essentially they are variables or methods pre defined by the system. For example the system variable __name__ can be used within any function and will always contain the name of that function. You can find more comprehensive information and examples [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames).

2) This concept of system reserved variables is fundamental in most programming languages. For example PHP refers to them as Magic Constants. The Python example above to get a function name can be achieved in PHP using __FUNCTION__. More examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 3):

1. Generally, "double underscore" methods are used internally by Python for certain builtin functions or operators (e.g. `__add__` defines behavior for the `+`). Those that do not have double underscores are just normal methods that wouldn't be used by operators or builtins. Now, these methods are still "normal" methods, in that you can call them just like any other method, but parts of the Python core treat them specially.
2. No, as far as I am aware, this is unique to Python, though many other languages support a similar idea (builtin/operator overloading) but through different mechanisms.

Shameless plug: I wrote a guide to this aspect of Python last year which is fairly comprehensive, you can read about how to use these methods on your own objects at http://rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html.

Comment: OK, question: Why can I do "1".__eq__("2") => False, but not 1.__eq__(2) => SyntaxError: invalid syntax ? A surprise to this new-to-Python programmer!

Comment: @MatthewCornell you can't call methods directly on numeric (integer or float) literals. `(1).__eq__(2)` should work.

Comment: Cool! But I don't understand. how is 1 different from (1)? I was thinking it's an operator precedence problem, e.g., the interpreter was looking for more after the period in 1.__eq__(2). From another question, 1..__eq__(2) *does* work.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> Certain classes of identifiers (besides keywords) have special
>   meanings. These classes are identified by the patterns of leading and
>   trailing underscore characters:
>
> _*
>
> Not imported by from module import *. The special identifier _ is used in the interactive interpreter to store the result of the last
>   evaluation; it is stored in the **builtin** module. When not in
>   interactive mode, _ has no special meaning and is not defined. See
>   section The import statement.
>
> Note The name _ is often used in conjunction with internationalization; refer to the documentation for the gettext
>   module for more information on this convention.
>
> __ * __
>
> System-defined names. These names are defined by the interpreter and its implementation (including the standard library). Current
>   system names are discussed in the Special method names section and
>   elsewhere. More will likely be defined in future versions of Python.
>   Any use of ***** names, in any context, that does not follow
>   explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.
>
> __*
>
> Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to
>   help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and
>   derived classes. See section Identifiers (Names).

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers

Answer (score 1):

These are special methods that are called in specific contexts.

[Read the documentation for the details.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names):

> A class can implement certain operations that are invoked by special
>   syntax (such as arithmetic operations or subscripting and slicing) by
>   defining methods with special names. This is Python’s approach to
>   operator overloading, allowing classes to define their own behavior
>   with respect to language operators. For instance, if a class defines a
>   method named `__getitem__()`, and x is an instance of this class, then
>   `x[i]` is roughly equivalent to `x.__getitem__(i)` for old-style classes
>   and `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)` for new-style classes. Except where
>   mentioned, attempts to execute an operation raise an exception when no
>   appropriate method is defined (typically `AttributeError` or `TypeError`).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, this convention is used in C with macros such as `__FILE__`.  Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, explicitly says this was his inspiration in his [blog on the history of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html).

Answer (score -2):

its used to indicate that the attributes are internal. there is no actual privacy in python, so these are used as hints yo indicate internals rather than api methods.

Comment: This would be true if the double underscores were only leading, and not trailing as well, e.g. `__hex`.